# Loop through API json responses and add them into one python dictionary

Tags: python, json, rest

I want to use the [OpenPageRank API](https://www.domcop.com/openpagerank/documentation) to get the 'page rank'and other stats from a list of domains.

Their documentation is in php and I'm having a tough time translating it, or getting it to work in my case.

The idea is to get the API responses and append them to a python dict or a .json file.

At the moment I have this function defined:

```
    headers = {'API-OPR': '%s' % opr_api_key}
    api_results = {}
    for items in domains_to_check:
        url = 'https://openpagerank.com/api/v1.0/getPageRank?domains%5B0%5D=' + items
        request = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        api_result = request.json()
```

The `domains_to_check` list is already predefined and it contains domains for a test.

Now as you can see above the code sends the request to the OPR and gets the json result it stores into the `api_result` and as expected it just adds the last API result.

I want to loop through all the domains in the list, send the request and append it to the results.

`dict.append[result]` doesn't work because the result is a .json file. Not a python dict.

I've tried transforming the result into the Python dict, but failed.

The API documentation hints that an array can be sent via [API from a single request](https://www.domcop.com/openpagerank/documentation) but failed to replicate this code from php.

Not sure how to solve this. Or how to approach it. Seems simple enough, but I just can't break it.

Any help welcomed.

Comment: Hm just saw this `%5B0%5D` in the URL is from PHP. I left it there since I could get the results from 1 domain and thought the problem is elsewhere. Will investigate there as well.

Comment: Why not use a List for it? As far as I can see you are not mentioning any key for associating the results with anything.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a list since you are not mentioning associating results with any key.

```
def send_domains_to_OPR():
    headers = {'API-OPR': '%s' % opr_api_key}
    api_results = []
    for items in domains_to_check:
        url = 'https://openpagerank.com/api/v1.0/getPageRank?domains%5B0%5D=' + items
        request = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        api_results.append(request.json())
```

If you want to match response with a list of domains to check you can always zip them:

```
for items, response in zip(domains_to_check, api_results):
  print(items)
  print(response)
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction. It helped a lot. 

Now, I understand I need to merge with the keys. Because ultimately, I want to be able to filter out all those domains that have < 1 domain rating lets say - or something to that extent. 

thanks, your answer helped a lot!

Comment: OK cool. You can filter this data structure by using [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), e.g. `list(filter(lambda response: response.rank > 1, responses))`. If solved then please accept the answer.